# Does adding fragments with tags cause them to not be destroyed when their parent is destroyed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an android application that uses one activity and a number of fragments to build a ui dynamically

The base activity has a simple LinearLayout in it that has nothing (BaseActivity)

I add a fragment to it that only contains a drawer layout with an actionbar a framelayout and a navigation bar (BaseFragment)

To that I add one of two fragments, one shows all children as lists (SerialFragment) , the other in a wizard style (WizardFragment)

Each of those can add one (in case of a wizard) or many (in case of a list) fragments (QuestionFragment)

When I navigate away from BaseActivity then the BaseFragment's onDestroy() gets called, but not the onDestroy() of any of the child fragments

I add the child fragments like so

```
FragmentTransaction trans = parent.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
set_default_animation(trans); //this just adds a custom animation
trans.replace(R.id.wizard_content, QuestionFragment.NewInstance(),question_id.toString()); //in case of a wizard
trans.add(R.id.list_content,QuestionFragment.NewInstance(), question_id.toString());//in case of a list
trans.commit();
```

The only difference between the BaseFragment (which gets destroyed) and the others, is that in the others I add a tag to them (section_id or question_id) so that I can retrieve them using findFragmentByTag.

Yet when the user navigates away from the activity only BaseFragment's onDestroy() is called.

Is the reason for this the fact that , that fragment is the only one I haven't added using a tag?

Note that I am not using a support fragment manager, the normal one, so I use tags to locate the fragments I want , since the non-support fragment manager does not contain getFragments().

Also note that I have not set the retain instance flag to true on any of the above mentioned fragments

I could test the above by removing tags and adding references to the fragments on the parents, but that means a LOT of refactoring which I would like to avoid if that is not the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refactoring everything, it seems that the tags weren't the problem (though I still removed them)

What fixed it for me, is using getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() to update the gui

That way when the base view gets destroyed its children are removed aswell

Hope it helps someone